# Flutter setFlashMode(FlashMode.always) does not work

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter app to monitor the blood pressure by placing the index finger on both camera and the flash light. In order to switch on the flash light, I am using the camera dependencies. When I set the `FlashMode` to `always`, it does not switch on the flash light. But if I set the `FlashMode` to `torch`, it switches on. Here the problem is, if use torch, I cant place my finger for longer time because of the heat emitted by the flash light. So is there a way to make it work with `FlashMode.always` or to reduce the power of the flash light while using the `FlashMode.torch`

Following is my implementation for switching the flashlight functionality :-

```
Future<void> _initController() async {
    try {
      List _cameras = await availableCameras();
      _controller = CameraController(_cameras.first, ResolutionPreset.low);
      await _controller.initialize();
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)).then((onValue) {
        _controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.torch);
        // _controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.always);   <----- this does not switch on the flashlight
      });
      _controller.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
        _image = image;
      });
    } catch (Exception) {
      debugPrint(Exception);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this ever going to go on the stores? There is actually very strict medical related standards...

Comment: @user15076841 no this for an academic work